# Is brightness of quasar jets related to the size of the black hole

Tags: black-holes, quasars

I think I read somewhere that brightness of infra red light from quasar( or UV light but red shifted to IR light) is related to the size of the black hole. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think brightness is more likely related to the amount of infalling matter available from the accretion disc. All quasars are powered by very large, supermassive black holes, but the biggest variable is the amount of matter available. Our own SMBH in Sagittarius is, perhaps fortunately, rather quiet, due to lack of fuel. Many billions of years ago it was probably far more violent, but has exhausted its fuel supplies.